# Howto determine if an SVN working copy needs updating (from a script)?

Tags: windows, svn, batch-file, build, build-automation

I'd like to determine from a batch file on Windows if a local SVN working copy needs to be updated from the server. On a unix-like machine, I would run "svn status -u" and count the '*'s. How do I achieve the same thing in a batch file?

Background: I'm trying to determine if a dependency library is out-of-date since it takes a *long* time to re-build it and we only update it about once every 3 months. This is for an automated build process.

Comment: You would also need to install a command line Subversion client, such as sliksvn

Comment: Refer this thread: [how do i know if my working copy is out of sync](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6516214/how-do-i-know-if-my-working-copy-is-out-of-sync)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm following you, maybe something like:

```
svn st -u | find "*"
if not "%errorlevel%"=="0" goto end

svn update

:end
```

find sets errorlevel to 0 if it successfully found "*".

**EDIT**:  accidentally left off the "" around %errorlevel%.

Comment: That will do, I'll just kick anyone who creates a filename containing a '*'.

Comment: I actually used `if not errorlevel 1 goto do_build` instead. (My logic is inverted from yours.)