# how do i know if my working copy is out of sync

Tags: svn

We keep a image of current release code in some local directory and for building the code we use the code in this directory. In the build script, I need a way to figure out if the code in image directory in sync with the current release branch in repository. If it is so, I will do a svn update from within script. Can the revision numbers be somehow used to detect the out of sync condition? If so how?

Vadiraj

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
svn status -u
```

adds working revision and server out-of-date information.

If you don't have non-versioned files in the directory then it's up to date only if the status command returns nothing.
Otherwise * means it's not up to date, ? means non-versioned, M - modified, etc.

In other words it's up to date if and only if the following returns 0:

```
svn status -u | grep -E -c "^\s+[^\?]"
```

Comment: I am sorry in the heading i wrote working copy. Its not actually working copy but image of source code. We'll not modify any files here and also everything is versioned. So if i do svn status -u and grep for * and i do find *s that means it is out of sync, then I'll do a svn update. But when I do a svn update, can conflicts arise. We have no M files in this local directory. If conflicts do arise how will i resolve it via script?

Comment: doing svn checkout also would bring latest files right? whats the diference between svn checkout and svn update?

Comment: If you don't modify the copy and you only update it periodically - then there can't be any conflicts

Comment: svn checkout is creating a working copy - that's done only once. svn update can be done on an already checked out working copy - it updates to the latest revision

Comment: btw, why do you need to check for out of sync before doing svn up - you can just do svn up - if it's up to the latest revision it will do nothing and will be very fast. Otherwise you'll run svn up anyways.

Comment: I believe the regex is not correct. If the idea is to match any lines that are whitespace then *, ?, M et al. It only matches a '?'. Alternative way to do it is svn status -u | wc -l. This will be 1 if up to date ('Status against revision:  xxxx'), but more than 1 if any local or remote changes.

Answer (score 0):

Fast and direct way:

```
repoVersion="$(svn status -u --depth empty <myWCdir> | awk '{print $NF}')"
wcVersion="$(svn info --show-item revision <myWCdir>)"
```

Then you can just compare those two numbers, as in:

```
if [[ $repoVersion -eq $wcVersion ]]; then
    echo "<myWCdir> is up to date"
else
    echo "<myWCdir> is out of date"
fi
```

Note: Plain `svn status -u` is way overkill. SVN bumps the rev# of a dir if any contents change (at any depth).